# Remove unused fields in form before submit

Tags: jquery, forms, email

I my be wrong in my thinking but... I thought that if I removed the name attribute of unused form fields from a form just before submit it would remove them from the resulting email tidying things up a little. My code doesn't seem to be working very well, any help would be welcome.

```
<script>
  function submitRequestForm(){
   requestForm = $("#formid");
    requestForm.find('input[name], select[name]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val(){
      $(this).removeAttr('name');
    }
    requestForm.submit();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing the name attribute, try disabling the field during form submit.

Before that there are few syntax errors in your code.

```
 function submitRequestForm(){
   requestForm = $("#formid");
    requestForm.find(":input").filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    requestForm.submit();

   // In case you want to re-enable the fields
   requestForm.find(":input").filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).removeAttr("disabled");

  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this killed the form on submit, it just gets stuck in a loop. Thanks for taking time to respond though, much appreciated.

Comment: It gets stuck in loop? May be because am trying to removeAttr from all input elements. Now i've updated it to remove only from those elements where we added before. Try again